# How to test speed of a web site at the time of development

Tags: web, performance-testing, bandwidth

I am new at web development. I have already developed a site. There are huge onload functions. This make me worried. Now I want to test the speed of this site before deployment. I wonder if there any tool to set up the site in different bandwidth. In simple how musvh time the site will take in 256 kbps, 512 kbps and 1mbps. Is there any such tools?

Thanks

Comment: Dreamweaver has this built-in function. But for loading time, it is in fact: **time taken = total file size / network speed**

Comment: @Shivan Raptor Don't forget that you also have to take into account bandwidth used for header, round trip time for every extra connection that needs to be made to download separate resources, the bandwidth for that, etc

Comment: Yes. Therefore, it is just an estimation.

Comment: Shivan, can you hint me little bit how this can be done with Dreamweaver?

Comment: On lower right corner of the main window, you can select the bandwidth speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fiddler.Go to rules menu and then Performance and select Simulate Model Speeds

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a slow-down proxy like [Sloppy](https://github.com/d6y/sloppy) against some browser plugins.

Browser tools are good for the actual speed measurement, not for slowing down the network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this one useful: http://gtmetrix.com/
It provides comprehensive analysis including onload performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for mobile web network simulation in iOS environment, iPhone Developer mode can help.

It is located at: **Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner**

To allow Developer mode, click "Use for Development" in Xcode organizer.